# For any square matrix F, is it possible that $\operatorname{rank}(F F^T-F^T F) = 1?$

Tags: matrix-rank

Given $F$ is any square matrix, let $F^T$ be the conjugate transpose.

Is it possible that $\operatorname{rank}(F F^T-F^T F) = 1?$?

It seems that it is impossible, but I don't know how to prove it.

On the other hand, is there specific name for the matrix in the form of $F F^T-F^T F$?

Comment: you may use MathJax in order to write formula

Comment: Thanks very much for editing my question. This is the first time I use MathJax so I am not familiar with the coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you mention conjugate transpose, I infer that the field is $\mathbb C$. The answer then is **no**.

$A:= FF^* - F^*F$
$A$ is Hermitian and hence diagonalizable.  This means $\text{rank}\big(A\big)=1$ can only occur because $\lambda_1 \neq0$ and $\lambda_k = 0$ for $k\in\big\{2,...,n\big\}$, but supposing this is true

$\lambda_1 $
$=  \lambda_1 + \big(\sum_{k=2}^n \lambda_k\big)$
$= \text{trace}\big(A\big) $
$= \text{trace}\big(FF^*-F^*F\big)$
$= \text{trace}\big(FF^*\big)-\text{trace}\big(F^*F\big)$
$=\text{trace}\big(FF^*\big)-\text{trace}\big(FF^*\big)$
$=0$
which is a contradiction